# Is $F_{\max(X_1, ..., X_n)} = F_{U[0,1]}^n$? Is $F^{-1}=F^{1/n}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Suppose that I have that $X_1, ..., X_n$ are iid random variables with distribution function $F$ and $U$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. If I have that $F(\max(X_1, ..., X_n)) = F_U^n$, that is, the CDF of the maximum is equal to the nth power of the distribution of the uniform random variable (over (0,1)), then how can I find the inverse cdf? I know that it should be $F^{1/n}$, but am unable to see the mathematics behind it because I am not sure how to find the inverse of the CDF. Would anyone have any ideas or tips? Thanks!

Comment: You want to show that $F^{-1}$ (a function from $[0,1]$ to $\bar{\mathbb R}$) equals $U^{1/n}$ (a function from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$)?

Comment: Hi, I guess I am ultimately trying to show that $max(X_1, ..., X_n)$ can be represented as $F^{-1}U^n$. Did I make a mistake in my thinking regarding the quantile function?

Comment: This is not what your question is saying. Anyway, you know that $F(M_n)=U^n$ and you want to deduce that $M_n=F^{-1}(U^n)$? Well...

Comment: @Did: I think that I managed to dig out the meaning in the OP.

Comment: @zoli And, to sum up, that would be that $F(M_n)$ is distributed like $U^{1/n}$? This would make sense but I cannot reconcile this with "If I have that $F(max(X_1, ..., X_n)) = F_U^n$" (which anyway is not what comes just afterwards either, namely, "the CDF of the maximum is equal to the nth power of the distribution of the uniform random variable")... *Riddles in the dark*, as they say. :-)

Comment: @Did: $F(M_n)$ is distributed like $U^n.$ (Not $U^{\frac1n}$ ) The "if I have" part is unnecessary of course. The OP does have $F(\max(X_1...X_1))=F_U^n.$

Comment: @zoli Hmmm: $P(F(M_n)<x)=x^n=P(U<x^n)=P(U^{1/n}<x)$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ hence $F(M_n)$ is distributed like... Fact checking: When $n$ grows, $M_n$ stochastically increases, so does $F(M_n)$, while $U^n$ decreases pointwisely hence also stochastically. Thus $F(M_n)=U^n$ in distribution is impossible for two different values of $n$.

Comment: @Did: Sorry, $P(F(M_n)<x)=x^n$ is like $P(U<x^n)$. That is, the distribution of $U^{1/n}$ behaves like the distribution of $M_n$. But this is my conclusion in my answer to "my question". Then what is wrong?

Comment: @zoli You lost me so let me recapitulate: $F(M_n)=U^n$ in distribution is wrong; $M_n=U^{1/n}$ in distribution is wrong in general; $F(M_n)=U^{1/n}$ in distribution is right (provided $F$ is continuous); what the OP asks is unclear to me. (I seem to have said nothing else.)

Comment: @Did: OK, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the monotonicity of $F$, the independence of the $X_i$'s and because of the fact the they are identically distributed, we have

$$P(F_{X_1}(\max(X_1,X_2,...,x_n))<x)=P(\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)<F_{X_1}^{-1}(x))=$$
$$P(X_1<F_{X_1}^{-1}(x)\cap X_2<F_{X_1}^{-1}(x)\cap \cdots \cap X_n <F_{X_1}^{-1}(x))=$$
$$=P(X_1<F_{X_1}^{-1}(x))^n.$$

And
$$P(X_1<F^{-1}_{X_1}(x))=F_{X_1}(F_{X_1}^{-1}(x))=x.$$

(If $0\le x\le 1$.) This is called uniform distribution over the unit interval.

So,

$$F_{\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)}(x)=P(F_{X_1}(\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n))<x)=x^n$$

for $0\le x\le 1$.

**This does not mean that $\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is the product of $n$ uniformly distributed random variables. This means simply that the distribution of $\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ equals the $n^{th}$ power of the uniform distribution over the unit interval.**

As far as the inverse of $F_{\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)}(x)=x^n$. Taking the $n^{th}$ root of both sides we get that

$$F_{\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)}^{\frac1n}(x)=x.$$

The definition of the inverse of $G(x)$ is that $G^{-1}(G(x))=x$. In this sense

$$F_{\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)}^{\frac1n}=F_{\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)}^{-1}.$$